# Why won't the runserver command in the terminal run? I am (a complete beginner) working on building a web app (learning log) with Django

Tags: python, django

So I've already created and activated a virtual environment, created a project, and an app (but the app shouldn't really matter at this point). I'm trying to view my project and ran the server command but it won't run. To clarify, I had already made more progress with the web app: created a model and migrated it so i could use it in the app, viewed the project as an admin to see the model working but when i created the second model, i had trouble migrating it. so i took a few steps back to the point where I could just view the empty project and that also didn't work so i'm confused. I could just delete and start over but I'd like to know what's wrong at this point. Below is what the terminal shows when I tried to run 'runserver' command so I could view the project on my local server.

```
C:\Users\acer>cd Desktop/programming/learning_log

C:\Users\acer\Desktop\programming\learning_log>ll_env\Scripts\activate

(ll_env) C:\Users\acer\Desktop\programming\learning_log>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

(ll_env) C:\Users\acer\Desktop\programming\learning_log>
```

Again, I had already managed to view the project through the admin site and even enter a topic (since I created a model for Topic) so obviously django is installed or at least was, and I did not delete any files or folders.

Comment: Are you sure you installed Django to virtual environment?

Comment: I did, yes. Is there a way I can check if it's there or if I somehow deleted it? I opened a different folder and i'm redoing the project. I compared the virtual env folder of the one i'm redoing (I just installed django so I know for sure it's there) and the one with the issues, and they have the same content, so does that confirm django is installed on the problematic one too?

Comment: You can check if Django is installed with the command: python -m django --version